# Android app signing with different or same keys?

Tags: android, certificate, android-keystore

Good day,
I have a question that might seen kindergarten in nature, but please go easy on me.

I have developed an app that works fine, and use a keystore, with a key value of "key0" and accompanying password. I have since developed a second app and I am using the same keystore, "key0" and password for uploads.

I thought that Google Play would complain citing security concerns if it didn't like using "key0" for app2 when uploading? Common sense would dictate using different keys for different apps, but if so, Google are happy to allow my app updates and issue them on the store!

I must admit that I am a novice when understanding certificates and keys - and this confusion has just been compounded by Google telling me that you cannot use the same key for different apps. I am confused by this, because on the App Signing page of the play console, although the upload certificates are the same for both apps, the app signing certificates. I am lost as to what all this means. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, Google wants the developers to use different keys for their app signing so that the key is confidential and anyone with that key can actually submit an update for your application if they are having the same package name that your application has.

Hence about the other question that you have, I think sometimes it is necessary to publish two or more applications using the same sign in key so that they can actually share the data between them. For example, Facebook and the Messenger app actually share the data between them and from my understanding, I think they use the same key to sign in their apps so that they can enable this data sharing.

I think [this is a good read](https://www.codementor.io/@maker-abhi/share-data-between-your-android-apps-only-securely-a0pa8ea0j).

Comment: Hey Reaz! how have you been? just wanted to pick your brain on activity to fragment conversion since it's your area of expertise! any idea about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910317/how-do-i-convert-my-activity-containing-tabs-and-viewpager-into-fragment-contain